# Sql-запрос ошибка

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Нужно чтобы прибавлялось 1 к числу в ячейке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну запрос должен работать. выполняйте его в MySQL. у вас явно тупит phpmyadmin

Comment: Я через другие сервера пробовал, через php. Ничего!

Comment: Что значит "через php" ? и что значит "ничего" ? те ошибки, что вы показали - это не ошибки MySQL, он таких выдавать не умеет. Это ошибки некого анализатора внутри самого phpmyadmin. Вот контрольный пример для MySQL, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e98d3/1 он работает корректно

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `users` SET `coin` = `coin` + 1 WHERE 1